# How to let the backend service know which form fields were modified

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my Angular app I have a form, which is used to edit existing records.
Once a record is edited, it is being sent to a WebAPI service to update the database.
Is there a way to make the WebAPI PUT method aware of which specific fields were modified, so there would be no need to override all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way for the backend to know which fields have changed.

The front end however, can inform the backend of the changed fields.

Let us say you have the following form:

```
<form name="example">
    <input type="text" name="color">
</form>
```

If you want to check if the input field was changed, you can use the following code in your controller - `$scope.example.color.$dirty` which will return a boolean value indicating if the form input was changed or not.

You can then pass this information along with the information present in the form to the backend which can then decide which fields to update.

You can take a look at this [article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) which explains form validation (and this process explains `$dirty`) which you may find useful.